# Python Numpy TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, eigenvalue

Here's my code:

```py
def topK(dataMat,sensitivity):
    meanVals = np.mean(dataMat, axis=0)
    meanRemoved = dataMat - meanVals
    covMat = np.cov(meanRemoved, rowvar=0)
    eigVals,eigVects = np.linalg.eig(np.mat(covMat))
```

I get the error in the title on the last line above. I suspect it has something to do with the datatype, so, here's an image of the variable and datatype from the Variable Explorer in Spyder:

[image: variable dtype]

I've tried changing `np.linalg.eig(np.mat(covMat))` to `np.linalg.eig(np.array(np.mat(covMat)))` and to `np.linalg.eig(np.array(covMat))`, nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the `dtype` og `covMat`?

Comment: As in the picture, it shows "object" (36 rows, 36 columns).

Comment: Ah, that's the `dtype`. Well that might very well be your problem. Try using `np.array(covMat, dtype=float)`. Does that convertion give you an error?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Your array has a `dtype` of `object`, but this should be some floating point `dtype`. Use e.g.

```
covMat = np.array(covMat, dtype=float)
```

to convert the `dtype`

Comment: This has helped me as well. I was using shap and I was getting this type conversion error. I had check one of my attribute was object changed to float and it worked . Thanks for solution

Answer (score 4):

If you got this error, that means the function you called used `np.isfinite` under the hood. Common functions that do so are `np.allclose`, `np.isclose` and `linalg` methods (as in the OP). As [jmd_dk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40809989/19123103) mentions, it usually means the dtype of your array is `object`.

A common fix is to cast the array to `float` dtype.

```py
covMat = covMat.astype(float)
```

Another common case is when concatenation / stack goes wrong or when the array comes from another datatype (e.g. pandas dataframes). In that case, try converting to a list first and then cast to `np.ndarray`.

```py
arr = np.array(arr.tolist())
```

For example, for the following case, straightforward recasting won't work but converting to a list and then into an ndarray works.

```py
arr = pd.Series([np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4]), np.array([5,6])]).values
# array([array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])], dtype=object)

np.array(arr, dtype=float)                  # <---- error
np.array(arr.tolist(), dtype=float)         # <---- no error
```