# how can I solve "TypeError ufunc 'isfinite'" in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a error about type. it comes from the stocker. I dont't know where the code error

the environment:
python 3.7
numpy and others libray are latest

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-00eba8b188be> in <module>
----> 3 amazon.changepoint_prior_analysis(changepoint_priors=[0.001, 0.01, 0.06, 0.2])

~\Desktop\master\stocker.py in changepoint_prior_analysis(self, changepoint_priors, colors)
    427             ax.fill_between(predictions['ds'].dt.to_pydatetime(), predictions['%.3f_yhat_upper' % prior],
    428                             predictions['%.3f_yhat_lower' % prior], facecolor = color_dict[prior],
--> 429                             alpha = 0.3, edgecolor = 'k', linewidth = 0.6)
    430 
    431         # Plot labels

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1599     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1600         if data is None:
-> 1601             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1602 
   1603         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in fill_between(self, x, y1, y2, where, interpolate, step, **kwargs)
   5222 
   5223         # Convert the arrays so we can work with them
-> 5224         x = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_xunits(x))
   5225         y1 = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_yunits(y1))
   5226         y2 = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_yunits(y2))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py in masked_invalid(a, copy)
   2364         cls = type(a)
   2365     else:
-> 2366         condition = ~(np.isfinite(a))
   2367         cls = MaskedArray
   2368     result = a.view(cls)

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I expect to show the complete chart,but now the actual lack some events.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem I encountered long back. I'm sharing the links. Hope so it would be helpful for you.[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432735/matplotlib-datetimes-and-typeerror-ufunc-isfinite-not-supported-for-the-inp?rq=1)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809503/python-numpy-typeerror-ufunc-isfinite-not-supported-for-the-input-types)