# shade area between 2 line plots ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code which correctly renders this:

```
plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Temp')
    plt.title('Min and Max temperature 2005-2014')
   
    # Plotting on the first y-axis
    minimum=new_df['min']
    maximum=new_df['max']
    plt.plot(new_df['Date'], new_df['min'], color='orange', label='Min')
    plt.plot(new_df['Date'], new_df['max'], color='olive', label='Max')
```

[image]

Now I need to colour the area between the 2 lines:

I tried this:

```
plt.fill_between(minimum, maximum, color='#539ecd')
```

but then I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    305                 pass
    306             else:
--> 307                 return printer(obj)
    308             # Finally look for special method names
    309             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    225 
    226     if 'png' in formats:
--> 227         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    228     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    229         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    117 
    118     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 119     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    120     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    121     if fmt == 'svg':

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2190                     orientation=orientation,
   2191                     dryrun=True,
-> 2192                     **kwargs)
   2193                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2194                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    543 
    544     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 545         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    546         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    547         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    462 
    463         try:
--> 464             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    465         finally:
    466             RendererAgg.lock.release()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1141 
   1142             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1143                 renderer, self, dsu, self.suppressComposite)
   1144 
   1145             renderer.close_group('figure')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, dsu, suppress_composite)
    137     if not_composite or not has_images:
    138         for zorder, a in dsu:
--> 139             a.draw(renderer)
    140     else:
    141         # Composite any adjacent images together

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2407             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2408 
-> 2409         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, dsu)
   2410 
   2411         renderer.close_group('axes')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, dsu, suppress_composite)
    137     if not_composite or not has_images:
    138         for zorder, a in dsu:
--> 139             a.draw(renderer)
    140     else:
    141         # Composite any adjacent images together

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1134         renderer.open_group(__name__)
   1135 
-> 1136         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
   1137         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
   1138                                                                 renderer)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in _update_ticks(self, renderer)
    967 
    968         interval = self.get_view_interval()
--> 969         tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
    970         if self._smart_bounds:
    971             # handle inverted limits

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    967 
    968         interval = self.get_view_interval()
--> 969         tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
    970         if self._smart_bounds:
    971             # handle inverted limits

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in iter_ticks(self)
    910         Iterate through all of the major and minor ticks.
    911         """
--> 912         majorLocs = self.major.locator()
    913         majorTicks = self.get_major_ticks(len(majorLocs))
    914         self.major.formatter.set_locs(majorLocs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in __call__(self)
    981     def __call__(self):
    982         'Return the locations of the ticks'
--> 983         self.refresh()
    984         return self._locator()
    985 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in refresh(self)
   1001     def refresh(self):
   1002         'Refresh internal information based on current limits.'
-> 1003         dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
   1004         self._locator = self.get_locator(dmin, dmax)
   1005 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in viewlim_to_dt(self)
    758             vmin, vmax = vmax, vmin
    759 
--> 760         return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
    761 
    762     def _get_unit(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in num2date(x, tz)
    399         tz = _get_rc_timezone()
    400     if not cbook.iterable(x):
--> 401         return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    402     else:
    403         x = np.asarray(x)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    252 
    253     ix = int(x)
--> 254     dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
    255 
    256     remainder = float(x) - ix

ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7fb311ea1cf8>
```

Edit:

dataframe looks like this:

```
Date  min  max  min2015  max2015
0   2014-01-01 -160  156     -133       11
1   2014-01-02 -267  139     -122       39
2   2014-01-03 -267  133      -67       39
3   2014-01-04 -261  106      -88       44
4   2014-01-05 -150  128     -155       28
```

and I convert the Date to datetime type like this:

```
  new_df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(new_df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Edit:

When I run:
plt.fill_between(new_df['Date'], minimum, maximum)

I get this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-0f6fcbb48fdc> in <module>()
     59 
     60 
---> 61 leaflet_plot_stations(400,'fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89')

<ipython-input-23-0f6fcbb48fdc> in leaflet_plot_stations(binsize, hashid)
     44     minimum = new_df['min']
     45     maximum =  new_df['max']
---> 46     plt.fill_between(new_df['Date'], minimum, maximum)
     47     #plt.scatter(new_df['Date'], new_df['min2015'], 'o')
     48     #plt.scatter(new_df['Date'], new_df['max2015'], 'o')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in fill_between(x, y1, y2, where, interpolate, step, hold, data, **kwargs)
   2999         ret = ax.fill_between(x, y1, y2=y2, where=where,
   3000                               interpolate=interpolate, step=step, data=data,
-> 3001                               **kwargs)
   3002     finally:
   3003         ax._hold = washold

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1890                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1891                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1892             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1893         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1894         if pre_doc is None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in fill_between(self, x, y1, y2, where, interpolate, step, **kwargs)
   4770 
   4771         # Convert the arrays so we can work with them
-> 4772         x = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_xunits(x))
   4773         y1 = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_yunits(y1))
   4774         y2 = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_yunits(y2))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py in masked_invalid(a, copy)
   2343         cls = type(a)
   2344     else:
-> 2345         condition = ~(np.isfinite(a))
   2346         cls = MaskedArray
   2347     result = a.view(cls)

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Can you describe the format of the values in `Date` (e.g. `new_df.dtypes`)?

Comment: its Date       datetime64[ns]

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: Can you provide the complete error when running `plt.fill_between(new_df['Date'], minimum, maximum)`?

Comment: done, see 2nd edit

Comment: I'm still unable to reproduce these errors. What are the versions of Python, matplotlib and pandas? (`import matplotlib as m;m.__version__`)

Comment: '2.0.0' ........

Comment: @LuisValencia And is your numpy version newer than [1.17.0](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/13218/files#diff-75d0951a28f1727cc71e0fa8a858a3f18d089e2da7511aa6bbaab6e0eb638b5f)?

Comment: 1.12.1 ... its a coursera environment ....

Comment: @LuisValencia I've updated my answer to work around the old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the fill is being tried horizontally over the time axis, and `minimum` and `maximum` contain values that aren't dates. I've looked up the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between):

> matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between(x, y1, y2=0, where=None, interpolate=False, step=None, *, data=None, **kwargs)

That was the first error.

Then with numpy newer than 1.17.0, you could just do:

```
size = 500

minimum = np.random.normal(0, 100, size)
minimum.sort()
minimum = np.random.randint(250, 300, size) - np.abs(minimum)
df = pd.DataFrame(minimum, 
                  pd.date_range("2005-01-01", periods=size, freq="d"),
                  columns=['min'],
                 )
df['max'] = df['min'] + np.random.randint(200, 250, size)
fig = df.plot()
fig.fill_between(df.index, df['min'], df['max'], color='#539ecd')
```

But from that second traceback, we can see that `fill_between` is trying `~(np.isfinite(a))` on all the axes. [Which isn't supported on older numpy.datetime64](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/13218/files#diff-75d0951a28f1727cc71e0fa8a858a3f18d089e2da7511aa6bbaab6e0eb638b5f), the type of your x-axis.

So we will have to use a numeric x-axis and then change the labels.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(minimum, 
                  columns=['min'],
                 )
df['max'] = df['min'] + np.random.randint(200, 250, size)
fig = df.plot()
fig.fill_between(df.index, df['min'], df['max'], color='#539ecd')
# We take the original datetime axis 
date_axis = pd.date_range("2005-01-01", periods=size, freq="d")
# and map a function from (axis, tick) -> wanted string
def label(axis, tick):
    tick = int(tick)
    if tick == len(axis):
        tick -= 1
    if 0 <= tick < len(axis):  
        return f"{axis[tick].year}-{axis[tick].month}"
    else:
        return ' '

fig.set_xticks(fig.get_xticks())  #silence a warning
fig.set_xticklabels(
    [label(date_axis, tick) for tick in fig.get_xticks()]
)
```

Comment: yeah I also read the documentation, and it seems very straightforward, but I get this error:  ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: @LuisValencia Is the `dtype` of  `minimum` or `maximum`, `object`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40809989/383793 From the sample data you shared, I'd say it should be save to cast to one of the integer types.

Comment: Date       datetime64[ns]
min                 int64
max                 int64
min2015             int64
max2015             int64
dtype: object

Comment: Oh wait.. Inifinity is always a float in python. I think if you use minimum.astype(float) and maximum.astype(float), it should work.

Comment: if you meant this:   plt.fill_between(new_df['Date'], minimum.astype(float), maximum.astype(float))
  doesnt work, same error :)

Answer (score 1):

`fill_between` takes the x coordinates as first argument. The following should work:

```py
plt.fill_between(new_df["Date"], minimum, maximum, color="lemonchiffon")
```

Note that using matplotlib 3.4 I could not reproduce the error. Whether the values in `Date` were converted to dates or were left as strings, `fill_between(minimum, maximum)` does not throw an error but does produce unexpected plots.

---

**Edit**

Using numpy 1.11.3 and matplotlib 2.0.2, I've been able to reproduce the `TypeError` raises by `np.isfinite` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45433424/13410397) for more information). Indeed this function  supports datetime64 only from version 1.17. **I highly suggest that you update the versions of matplotlib and numpy**. However, using the earlier versions described in this paragraph, the error was bypassed by explicitly casting the dates:

```py
plt.fill_between(np.array(new_df["Date"]), minimum, maximum, color='lemonchiffon')
```

Comment: I tried but I get this error: TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''