# Contour Plot of a huge matrix

Tags: python, matrix, plot, contour

I am trying to make a contour plot in python for a huge matrix of size 772*14678. But in every approach I am facing the traceback: TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'. Is there any possible way to resolve this issue?

Tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=None)
data_array = data.values

data_array = np.nan_to_num(data_array, nan=0)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.contourf(data_array, levels=20, cmap='viridis')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Contour Plot')
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for other questions about `TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite'` to make sure your case is not a duplicate of a previous question. E.g. [Python Numpy TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40809503/1609514)